# STM32 Temperature sensor power off

Tags: stm32, temperature, adc, hal

I am using internal ADC temp sensor , in a low power device without the sensor in stop mode ,the uController consumes around 4 uA but when the temp sensor is on the consumption goes up to 8-9 uA 
the problem is i can not turn the sensor OFF / i just measured the off current by setting it off from start by stmcube

i am searching for a code that can turn off the temp sensor 
up until now i have tested these:

1-

```
HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc);
hadc.Lock=HAL_UNLOCKED;
__HAL_UNLOCK(&hadc);
HAL_ADCEx_DisableVREFINTTempSensor();
```

2-

```
ADC1->CR&=0X00000000;
ADC->CCR&=~(1<<23);
```

i prefer to work with HAL , it dose not seems to cut the Sensor power

Comment: Which STM32 are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ADC1->CR &= 0x00000000;` line looks wrong to me, depending on the controller you're using.

There is usually a bit to disable the ADC which needs to be set, rather than writing all 0s. Try `ADC1->CR = (0x01 << 1);` instead. If you have the ST Micro written defines for your processor `ADC1->CR = ADC_CR_ADDIS;` should be the same but more readable. After disabling the ADC you will be able to turn off the `TSEN` bit of `ADC->CCR`.

Comment: thanks . by the way i am saying this for other people if they have the same problem , this steps must be done before MSPDeinit , otherwise it wont work .